# Handling Exceptions with Bulk API Requests

Tags: python, pandas, api, dataframe, exception

I am pulling data from an API that allows batch requests, and then storing the data to a Dataframe. When there is an exception with *one* of the items being looked up via the API, I want to either skip that item entirely, (or write zeroes to the Dataframe) and then go on to the next item.

But my issue is that because the API data is being accessed in bulk (i.e., not looping through each item in the list), an exception for *any* item in the list breaks the program. So how can I elegantly handle exceptions without looping through each individual item in the `tickers` list?

Note that removing `ERROR` from the `tickers` list will enable the program to run successfully:

```
import os
from iexfinance.stocks import Stock
import iexfinance

# Set IEX Finance API Token (Sandbox)
os.environ['IEX_API_VERSION'] = 'iexcloud-sandbox'
os.environ['IEX_TOKEN'] = 'Tpk_a4bc3e95d4c94810a3b2d4138dc81c5d'

# List of companies to get data for
tickers = ['MSFT', 'ERROR', 'AMZN']

batch = Stock(tickers, output_format='pandas')
income_ttm = 0

try:
    # Get income from last 4 quarters, sum it, and store to temp Dataframe
    df_income = batch.get_income_statement(period="year")
    print(df_income)

except (iexfinance.utils.exceptions.IEXQueryError, iexfinance.utils.exceptions.IEXSymbolError) as e:
    pass
```

Comment: If those are your real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones. Editing them out of your question is _**not enough**_. (I suspect the provider wouldn't want you sharing even your sandbox credentials.)

Comment: Appreciate the concern but those are "throwaway" credentials that are not tied to my account. Additionally, they are sandbox credentials, which means the data they return is randomized. I just figured it was easier to share some token so that people could actually run the code themselves.

Comment: Do you want to return exsting data? Do you want to tell the user which column fail?

Comment: @ndclt - Ideally would like for the output to just show 0s for the data that the API failed to look up. So in this example when there are no exceptions, the output looks something like: ```MSFT AMZN``` as the column headers, and then the rows are data returned from the API. Instead, I would like the column headers to be ```MSFT ERROR AMZN``` and still the rows are the returned API data from ```MSFT``` and ```AMZN```. But for all the rows for ```ERROR``` to be 0 (since the API couldn't find data for it).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```py
import os
from copy import deepcopy

from iexfinance.stocks import Stock
import iexfinance

def find_wrong_symbol(tickers, err):
    wrong_ticker = []
    for one_ticker in tickers:
        if one_ticker.upper() in err:
            wrong_ticker.append(one_ticker)
    return wrong_ticker

# Set IEX Finance API Token (Sandbox)

os.environ['IEX_API_VERSION'] = 'iexcloud-sandbox'
os.environ['IEX_TOKEN'] = 'Tpk_a4bc3e95d4c94810a3b2d4138dc81c5d'

# List of companies to get data for
tickers = ['MSFT', 'AMZN', 'failing']

batch = Stock(tickers, output_format='pandas')
income_ttm = 0

try:
    # Get income from last 4 quarters, sum it, and store to temp Dataframe
    df_income = batch.get_income_statement(period="year")
    print(df_income)

except (iexfinance.utils.exceptions.IEXQueryError, iexfinance.utils.exceptions.IEXSymbolError) as e:
    wrong_tickers = find_wrong_symbol(tickers, str(e))
    tickers_to_get = deepcopy(tickers)
    assigning_dict = {}
    for wrong_ticker in wrong_tickers:
        tickers_to_get.pop(tickers_to_get.index(wrong_ticker))
        assigning_dict.update({wrong_ticker: lambda x: 0})
    new_batch = Stock(tickers_to_get, output_format='pandas')
    df_income = new_batch.get_income_statement(period="year").assign(**assigning_dict)
```

I create a small function in order to find tickers that are not handle by the API. After deleting the wrong tickers, I recall the API without it and with the `assign` function add the missing columns with the `0` values (it could be anything, a `NaN` or another default value).